# Setting a timer with different values

Tags: c#, timer

I currently am using a single timer. This timer is set so every two seconds it will switch to the next case in the case switch. However I now want to be able to set the timer to a different amount of seconds. I would like to have three or four more different values.
I know I can create new timers and then from that get the event handler for each one however I don't want to do that here.
Is there a way that I can set a single timer to different values?
The code I currently have is listed below:

```
Clock = new Timer(2000);
           Clock.Elapsed += Clock_Elapsed;
            Clock.Enabled = true;
            Clock.Start();   

 private void Clock_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (CurrentDevice)
            {
                case (Devices.WSS):
                    if (OurWSS.CurrentComponent != null)
                    {
                        OurRobot.LoadComponent(OurComponent);
                        OurWSS.UnLoad();                    
                    }
                    CurrentDevice = Devices.Robot
                    break;
                case (Devices.Robot):
                    if (OurRobot.CurrentComponent != null)
                    {
                        OurMachine.LoadComponent(OurComponent);
                        OurRobot.UnLoad();
                    }
                    CurrentDevice = Devices.Machine;
                    break;
                case (Devices.Machine):
                    if (OurMachine.CurrentComponent != null)
                    {
                        OurRobot.LoadComponent(OurComponent);
                        //OurComponent.GetCurrentOperation();
                        OurMachine.UnLoad();
                    }
                    CurrentDevice = Devices.RobotOut;
                    break;
                case (Devices.RobotOut):
                    if (OurRobot.CurrentComponent != null)
                    {
                        OurWSS.LoadComponent(OurComponent);
                        OurRobot.UnLoad();
                    }
                    CurrentDevice = Devices.WSS;
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: One timer is needed per interval I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't set a single timer to return multiple intervals, but if the intervals you want are multiples of some single value it would be easy enough to ignore the ticks until the desired interval occurs.

There are many possible ways to do this. Here's an example I've used in Unity game programming: imagine you want to respond on 1-second, 5-second, and 10-second intervals. First, initialize a 3-slot array containing the current time plus 1, 5, and 10 seconds, and set the timer to 1-second intervals. On each timer-tick test whether the current time is equal to or greater than each slot, and if true, execute the corresponding action and update the array slot to the next target time for that slot's interval.

The updated target time could be relative to the real current time or relative to the time stored in the slot, depending on whether it's more important to get as close as possible to fixed or relative intervals.

This is also easily abstracted into a class if you'll be doing a lot of this.

Comment: I think this is what I want to do. In the event I posted above in one of the case switches instead of it switching every two seconds I want it to be either 4, 5 or 6 seconds. This seems like a good way to do this. Thankyou

Comment: Happy to help. Since you're new to stackoverflow, I'll point out you should mark an answer as accepted if it solves your problem. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can change timer's interval by using `Clock.Interval = 3000`. [Timer.Interval Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.interval(v=vs.110).aspx)

Also there is no need to call `Start()` method after `Clock.Enabled = true;`, if you take a look to `Start()` implementation, it is just setting `Enabled` to `true`.

```
 /// <devdoc>
 /// <para>Starts the timing by setting <see cref='System.Timers.Timer.Enabled'/> to <see langword='true'/>.</para>
 /// </devdoc>
 public void Start() {
     Enabled = true;
 }
```

Source: [Timer Start()](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/services/timers/system/timers/Timer.cs,d8d4c6fbc471f649,references)

Comment: Thank you for the helpful information. I am still very new to C# programming so I'm still trying to find my feet. I will have a look into the Clock.Interval and see what I can find.

Comment: This won't allow multiple values simultaneously, which is how I interpreted the question.

Comment: @McGuireV10 _"However I now want to be able to set the timer to a different amount of seconds."_, _"Is there a way that I can set a single timer to different values?"_, yes there is a way, you can change single timer's interval. I can't see anywhere word _"simultaneously"_.

Answer (score 0):

If you limit usage to multiply of a second you could try creating a counter, increase it in every tick and than check if is time to execute a method:

```
    long seconds;

    private void Clock_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        seconds++;
        ExecAction1Second(); -- action taht executes every second
        if (seconds % 2 == 0)
            ExecAction2Seconds(); -- action taht executes every 2 seconds
        if (seconds % 3 == 0)
            ExecAction3Seconds(); -- action taht executes every 3 seconds
    }
```